# Oracle 12c with Data-guard, create PDB failed

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

There are two databases orcl1&orcl2 with data-guard, db_name is 'orcl', primary db is orcl1. The datafiles path both are '/oracle/orcl/'. I try to create a new PDB 'pdb1' in orcl1. Use command like

```
create pluggable database pdb1 admin user oracle identified by oracle
 default tablespace  pdb1   datafile '/oracle/orcl/pdb1/pdb101.dbf' size 20g autoextend on  
 path_prefix = '/oracle/pdb1/'  
 file_name_convert =('/oracle/orcl/pdbseed/', '/oracle/orcl/pdb1/');
```

And then ora-65005, missing or invalid file name pattern file ----/oracle/orcl2/pdbseed/temp01.dbf. Actually it should be '/oracle/orcl/pdbseed/temp01.dbf'. Parameter db_file_name_convert both are empty.How to solve this error or create PDB successfully in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the command:

```
create pluggable database pdb1 admin user oracle identified by oracle
 default tablespace  pdb1   datafile '/oracle/orcl/pdb1/pdb101.dbf' size 20g autoextend on  
 path_prefix = '/oracle/pdb1/'  
 file_name_convert =('/oracle/orcl/pdbseed/', '/oracle/orcl/pdb1/', 
                     '/oracle/orcl2/pdbseed/', '/oracle/orcl/pdb1/'); -- wherever the dg stores its datafiles
```